# Connectycube react-native video recording

Tags: react-native, connectycube

does **Connectycube** react native supports video call recording or saving?
i was following the official docs of connectycube react native but video recording feature isn't there.

https://developers.connectycube.com/reactnative/videocalling

Answer (score 0):

- re local recording - no it does not as for now, because of the limitations in https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-webrtc library. Unfortunately  - there is simply no support of streams recording locally.
- re server sied recording - an additional info can be found here https://connectycube.com/2021/02/23/connectycube-releases-server-side-calls-recording-along-with-new-meetings-api/